# Losing modelattribute between methods

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

This controller works as it should

```
@SessionAttributes("giveForm")
@Controller
public class GiveFormController {

    private PersonDao personManager;
    private KeyCardManager database;
    private GiveFormValidator validator;

    public GiveFormController() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public GiveFormController(KeyCardManager database, PersonDao personManager, GiveFormValidator validator) {

        this.database = database;
        this.validator = validator;
        this.personManager = personManager;
    }

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(getValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/give", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String give(Model model) {
        GiveForm giveForm = new GiveForm();

        model.addAttribute(giveForm);

        return "give";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"continue"})
    public String go(@ModelAttribute("giveForm") @Valid GiveForm giveForm,
            BindingResult result, Model model, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String customer = giveForm.getCustomer();

        if (!customer.isEmpty()) {
            Person person = getPersonManager().findByUid(customer);

            if (person != null) {
                model.addAttribute("customerName", person.getCn());
                model.addAttribute("userIdActive", person.isActive());
            }
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            return "give";

        } else {

            return "give-confirm";

        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"cancel"})
    public String cancel(@ModelAttribute("giveForm") GiveForm giveForm, SessionStatus status) {

        status.setComplete();

        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"ready"})
    public String ready(@ModelAttribute("giveForm") GiveForm giveForm, SessionStatus status,
          HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        System.out.println(giveForm.getKeyId());

         status.setComplete();

        model.addAttribute(giveForm);

      if(getDatabase().insertGive(giveForm, request.getRemoteUser())) {
        return "success";
      }
      else {
            return "operationfailed";
      }
    }
```

But this returns null when getting the modelattribute to ready-method:

```
@SessionAttributes("takeForm")
@Controller
public class XXTakeFormController {

private TakeFormValidator validator;
private KeyCardManager database;
private PersonDao ldap;

   public XXTakeFormController(){

   }
   @Autowired
    public XXTakeFormController(TakeFormValidator validator, KeyCardManager database, PersonDao ldap) {

        this.database = database;
        this.validator = validator;
        this.ldap = ldap;

    }
     @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(getValidator());
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/take", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String take(Model model) {

        TakeForm takeForm = new TakeForm();

        model.addAttribute(takeForm);

        return "take";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"continue"})
    public String go(@ModelAttribute("takeForm") @Valid TakeForm takeForm,
            BindingResult result, Model model, SessionStatus status) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "take";
        }

        else {
             String criteria = takeForm.getCriteria();
        if (Character.isDigit(criteria.charAt(0))) {
          // criteria is a keyId
          String customer = getDatabase().getHolderOf(criteria);
          takeForm.setCustomer(customer);
          Person person = getLdap().findByUid(customer);
          if (person != null) {
            model.addAttribute("customerName", person.getCn());
          }
          model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
          List keys = new ArrayList();
          keys.add(getDatabase().getKey(criteria));
          model.addAttribute("keys", keys);
        } else {
          // criteria is a userId
          takeForm.setCustomer(criteria);
          model.addAttribute("customer", criteria);
          model.addAttribute("customerName", getLdap().findByUid(criteria).getCn());
          model.addAttribute("keys", getDatabase().getKeysOf(criteria));
        }

    }
            return "take-confirm";

    }

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"cancel"})
    public String cancel(@ModelAttribute("takeForm") TakeForm takeForm,
             SessionStatus status) {

        status.setComplete();

        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"ready"})
    public String ready(@ModelAttribute("takeForm") TakeForm takeForm, SessionStatus
            status, HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {

          status.setComplete();
        model.addAttribute(takeForm);

        System.out.println(takeForm.getKeyId());




        if(getDatabase().executeTake(takeForm.getKeyId(), request.getRemoteUser(), takeForm.getNotes())){

        return "success";
        }
        else {
            return "operationfailed";
        }
    }
```

It is probably something I'm blind to. Both ready-methods return the same simple view. Can someone borrow eyes for me? :)

Comment: Do you execute give() method before ready() one? Because it's in the give() method where you instanciate the object and add it to the model. When you use @SessionAttribute("giveForm") and then @ModelAttribute("giveForm") spring looks for "giveForm" in the session and if you hadn't added the "giveForm" object to the model it returns null. You have to intanciate the object manually and add it to the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
model.addAttribute("key","value");
```

It is mainly used to set the data to model in controller. That data will be retrieved in jsp file directly by using key name as `${key}`
All the data, which is added to the Model will be accessed in the jsp file directly by using `${name}`.